# find couple of words which if deleting one letter will print the couple of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, list

When given a string I need to find similar words which have a difference in a letter. "no" and "noc" are similar words with a difference in one letter without using libraries or short functions

for example:
if I have the string "car ucar nor or caar"
will print:
car---ucar
nor---or
car---caar

I have this code:
what I need to change in order that the code will work?
also I don't know how to define j that will start from the next word in the 0 index.
Thank you for the help!

```
def Difference(s):
    list=s.split(" ")
    i=0
    countDigit=0
    for word1 in range(len(list)):
      for word2 in range(len(list)):
        if word1[i]==word1[j]:
            i+=1
            j+=1
            continue
    elif word1[i]!=word[j]:
             countDigit+=1
             if countDigit==1:
                 print(word1,"--- ",word2)
    else:
            break


    s="car ucar nor or caar"
    Difference(s)
```

Comment: What does not work in this code?

Comment: note you have double double-quotes in your second-to-last line; should be "car ucar nor or caar", not ""car ucar nor or caar""

Comment: @user3385217 you are not being very clear

Comment: You need to provide some more details here. I would suggest a list of rules and few more examples

Comment: @urban is it clearer now?

Comment: @user3385217 Added 3 versions of the same way of thinking. The last one should be the most complete and efficient - let me know if you need more clarification on how this works

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to solve it in my way. and  I get the error TypeError("'int' object is not subscriptable") on the row     if word1[i]==word1[j]:

Answer (score 0):

The [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#) library can help you.
The code below will print all the elements in the list that differ by one character. 
Diffib provides an efficient way find the differences.

By doing a nested iteration over the list you can test each item against every other item.

The list comprehension adds all the differences to a list, and then counts the differences - if there is only one, then the criteria is met and the string is printed.

```
def Differences(s):
    sl = s.split(" ")
    for t in sl: 
        for u in sl: 
            difflist = [diff for diff in difflib.ndiff(t,u) if diff[0] != ' '] 
            if len(difflist) == 1: 
                print ("{}---{}".format(t,u)) 

s = 'car ucar nor or caar'
Differences(s)
```

This will give output of:

```
car---ucar
car---caar
ucar---car
nor---or
or---nor
caar---car
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [function](https://github.com/hansrajdas/algorithms/blob/master/Level-2/are_two_strings_one_edit_away.c#L44) to check if two strings are one edit away or not.

Call this function for every pair of strings and if this returns `TRUE` print that couple otherwise pass next pair of string to this function.

You will have to convert this algorithm in Python, would be an easy task!

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, the following is a good start:

```
def letter_remove(from_str, target_str):
    """
    For each letter of from_str - remove it and check if it matches target_str
    """
    for i in range(len(from_str)):
        new_word = from_str[:i] + from_str[i+1:]
        if new_word == target_str:
            print(target_str,"--- ",from_str)

def difference(s):
    list=s.split(" ")
    for word1 in list:
        for word2 in list:
            if word1==word2:
                continue

            letter_remove(word2, word1)
            letter_remove(word1, word2)


s="car ucar nor or caar"
difference(s)
```

This will give you:

```
$ python2 ~/tmp/test.py
('car', '--- ', 'ucar')
('car', '--- ', 'caar')
('car', '--- ', 'caar')
('car', '--- ', 'ucar')
('or', '--- ', 'nor')
('or', '--- ', 'nor')
('car', '--- ', 'caar')
('car', '--- ', 'caar')
```

Observations:

- We need to compare word1 to word2 and the reverse since removing a letter from word1 might result in word2
- The results need deduplication

### A better (maybe) version

- We can use sets to ensure that the elements in the set are unique
- Instead of printing we add each combination in the set as a tuple
- We return all sets and print them at the end

---

```
def letter_remove(from_str, target_str):
    """
    For each letter of from_str - remove it and check if it matches target_str

    Returns:
        A set of unique combinations found
    """
    results = set()
    for i in range(len(from_str)):
        new_word = from_str[:i] + from_str[i+1:]
        if new_word == target_str:
            # Sort words
            a, b = target_str, from_str
            results.add((target_str, from_str))

    return results

def difference_set(s):
    list=s.split(" ")
    all_results = set()
    for word1 in list:
        for word2 in list:
            if word1==word2:
                continue

            all_results.update(letter_remove(word2, word1))
            all_results.update(letter_remove(word1, word2))

    return all_results

# This returns a set (unique elements) of the found differences
s="car ucar nor or caar"
sets = difference_set(s)
for s in sets:
    print(s)
```

The output of the above is

```
$ python2 ~/tmp/test.py
('or', 'nor')
('car', 'caar')
('car', 'ucar')
```

Observations:

- The above is a very inefficient algorithm since it will create too many strings for all possible letter removal and I would not recommend it for very long inputs. A smarter algorithm could compare each letter in the words and allow skipping one mismatching index

### A definitely better approach

Comments inline

```
def letter_remove2(from_str, target_str):
    """
    For each letter of from_str - remove it and check if it matches target_str

    Returns:
        True: if the two strings can be matched by removing a character from one
    """
    skipped_a_letter = False
    i = 0
    j = 0

    # if they differ by more than a letter, then we do not accept them
    if abs(len(from_str) - len(target_str)) > 1:
        return False

    # Loop target's letters
    while i < len(target_str):
        if target_str[i] == from_str[j]:
            j += 1
            i += 1
            continue

        # If we have not already skipped a letter from from_str, skip this one
        # by increasing j but not i!
        if not skipped_a_letter:
            j += 1

            # Ensure we have not exceeded the length of from_str
            if len(from_str) <= j:
                return False

            skipped_a_letter = True
            continue

        # If we reach here, it means that character do not match and we have
        # already attempted to skip a letter - no match after all
        return False

    # If we successfully loop, it means that we can match by removing a letter
    return True

def difference_set(s):
    list=s.split(" ")
    all_results = set()
    for word1 in list:
        for word2 in list:
            if word1==word2:
                continue

            if letter_remove2(word2, word1):
                # Keep the target word first in the set since it will always
                # be the shorter one
                all_results.add((word1, word2))

            if letter_remove2(word1, word2):
                all_results.add((word2, word1))

    return all_results
```

Output:

```
('or', 'nor')
('car', 'caar')
('car', 'ucar')
```

Comment: Note: this can be further optimized to reduce the number of loops... but I leave this up to you